# cannot use any yum command "global name 'IncrementalDecoder' is not defined"

Tags: centos6, python, yum

On my CentOS 6.9 64bit system each time i write any related yum command,the answer is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/yum", line 29, in <module>
    yummain.user_main(sys.argv[1:], exit_code=True)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 298, in user_main
    errcode = main(args)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 115, in main
    base.getOptionsConfig(args)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/cli.py", line 229, in getOptionsConfig
    self.conf
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 911, in <lambda>
    conf = property(fget=lambda self: self._getConfig(),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 335, in _getConfig
    startupconf.pluginconfpath,disabled_plugins,enabled_plugins)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 564, in doPluginSetup
    plugin_types, confpath, disabled_plugins, enabled_plugins)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/plugins.py", line 159, in __init__
    self._importplugins(types)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/plugins.py", line 211, in _importplugins
    nxt = ' ' * (utf8_width(key) - 2) + ': '
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/i18n.py", line 218, in utf8_width
    for (ucs, bytes) in __utf8_iter_ucs(msg):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/i18n.py", line 174, in __utf8_iter_ucs
    for byte0 in uiter:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/i18n.py", line 170, in __utf8_iter_ints
    for byte in to_utf8(msg):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/i18n.py", line 436, in to_utf8
    obj = obj.encode('utf-8', errors)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/encodings/__init__.py", line 120, in search_function
    entry = getregentry()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/encodings/utf_8.py", line 39, in getregentry
    incrementaldecoder=IncrementalDecoder,
NameError: global name 'IncrementalDecoder' is not defined
```

yum clean all and remove and reinstall yum not resolve the problem.

Any hint?

Regards

Comment: Looks like you have problem with your `yum` installation. Have you modified any yum or python files?

Comment: Check from where it wants to import `IncrementalDecoder`, as I can see it is likely in a python2.6 core module, so it seems you have to reinstall python2.6. Of course you can't do it with yum :-) But downloading the rpm, and installing it manually (`rpm -i`) may work.

Answer (score 0):

Some people had a similar problem and it was python related.

Try installing  python-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64.rpm and type `hash -r python`

References :

- http://mir01.syntis.net/CentOS/6.9/os/x86_64/Packages/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35387191/python-getting-symbol-not-found-pycodecinfo-getincrementaldecoder

Answer (score 0):

Installing http://mir01.syntis.net/CentOS/6.9/os/x86_64/Packages/python-libs-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64.rpm

Solve my issue:

rpm -iv --replacepkgs python-libs-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64.rpm

Thnak you...